# Lovasz Extension of the Product of Functions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, convex-analysis

Let $f$ and $g$ be submodular functions, and
let $\widehat{f}$ and $\widehat{g}$ be the Lovasz extensions of $f$ and $g$, respectively.

What can we say about the Lovasz extension of $f \times g$,  i.e.  $\widehat{f\times g}$ ?

In particular, is there any result that helps getting and explicit formulation of the Lovasz extension of $f \times g$ ?

Is there any result stating that we can express $\widehat{f\times g}$ in terms of $\widehat{f}$ and $\widehat{g}$ ?

What if we further assume that $f$ is modular ?

Comment: Note that without extra assumptions, the product of submodular functions is not necessarily submodular. Also, could you be more specific what you mean by "explicit formulation"? What's wrong with using one of the definitions of Lovasz extension?

Comment: @p.s. You are right. I added the case when one of the functions is modular. By explicit formulation I mean that the Lovasz extension of the multiplication is expressed in terms of f and g.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you had in mind, but in the very special case where $f$ and $g$ are both normalized modular functions, this formula works:
$$
\widehat{f \times g} (x) = \sum_i \sum_j \hat{f}(e_i) \hat{g}(e_j) \min(x_i,x_j)
$$
In general, you can use the values of the $\hat{f}, \hat{g}$ to get the values of the $f,g$, which gives you the values of $f\times g$, and plug those into a formula for the Lovasz extension to get $\widehat{f \times g}$. For example:
$$
\widehat{f \times g}(x) = E_{t \sim U(0,1)} \hat{f}( [x > t] )\hat{g}( [x > t] )
$$
$$
[x > t]_i = \begin{cases} 0 & x_i \le t\\ 1 & x_i > t\end{cases}
$$
While it's an explicit formula in terms of values of $\hat{f}, \hat{g}$, it may not be that useful.

Comment: @p.s.This formula is wonderful. Do you have any references ?

Comment: The characterization of the Lovasz extension as an expectation is mentioned [here](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/3871-beyond-convexity-online-submodular-minimization.pdf). A good reference for submodularity and the Lovasz extenstion in general is [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1111.6453).